# Is there a way to copy font formatting from one Font2 to another?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm writing a PowerPoint VBA macro to change typed bullet characters at the start of the line (like "・" typed in as part of the paragraph text) to bullet-lists (i.e. bullets as part of the paragraph formatting). I want the bullets in the list to look exactly like the bullets did as typed characters, meaning that I need to copy all the formatting information inside `TextRange2.Characters(1).Font` for the bullet character as typed text to `TextRange2.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font` for the new bullet as a feature of the paragraph formatting. Is there a quick way to do a deep copy like this?

From what I gather, I may need to make a bunch of helper `Sub`s to do a deep copy of all the `Font2` properties. (I know I can't just do `Set TextRange2.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font = TextRange2.Characters(1).Font` because the `TextRange2.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font` property is read-only.)

Here are some but not all of the helper `Sub`s I would need if I follow this route.

```vb
Public Sub CopyFont2(destination As Font2, source As Font2)
Public Sub CopyFillFormat(destination As FillFormat, source As FillFormat)
Public Sub CopyGlowFormat(destination As GlowFormat, source As GlowFormat)
Public Sub CopyColorFormat(destination As ColorFormat, source As ColorFormat)
Public Sub CopyLineFormat(destination As ColorFormat, source As ColorFormat)
```

I haven't started writing any of these except for `CopyFont2` and `CopyFillFormat`, and I would rather avoid writing all these if I can. Is there a simpler way to do a deep copy on built-in objects this? Or is there an alternative way to copy font formatting that I'm missing?

Comment: If you generate the new textrange objects from the clipboard (i.e. clipboard-copy from source, then paste), you'll get a deep-copy...

Comment: That's not a best practice, since you're piling local formatting on local formatting. Future users of this deck will have a better experience if you format the **Slide Master** and **Slide Layouts** with your preferred format, then **Reset** each slide to update the appearance to the layout.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you for the info. Unfortunately I think I might be in an unsupported fringe case because I am trying to copy to a BulletFormat2 object, not a TextRange or TextRange2.

Comment: @JohnKorchok Thank you for raising that concern. Local formatting isn't a huge  concern because the application is for prepping documents for import into a computer-assisted translation program, not for making robust templates or presentations that last beyond their single use. Nevertheless your point is a good one because the route I was on would put a bunch of formatting info inside the bullet

Answer (score 1):

Here is my extremely brute force way of dealing with a similar issue, which covers a case where I needed to copy all formatting from one shape to another with the exact same text:

```
Sub copyAllTextFormatting(oShp As Shape, tShp As Shape)

Debug.Print "IN_copyAllTextFormatting"
On Error GoTo Errhandler

Dim tmpRange As TextRange
Dim tmpRange2 As TextRange2



Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
    If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
        Set tmpRange = tShp.TextFrame.TextRange
        Set tmpRange2 = tShp.TextFrame2.TextRange

        With oShp.TextFrame
            .MarginBottom = tShp.TextFrame.MarginBottom
            .MarginLeft = tShp.TextFrame.MarginLeft
            .MarginRight = tShp.TextFrame.MarginRight
            .MarginTop = tShp.TextFrame.MarginTop
            .Orientation = tShp.TextFrame.Orientation
            .VerticalAnchor = tShp.TextFrame.VerticalAnchor
            .WordWrap = tShp.TextFrame.WordWrap
        End With

        For j = 1 To tmpRange.Paragraphs.Count

            With oShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat
                If tmpRange.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.Bullet = msoTrue Then
                    .Bullet.visible = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.visible
                    .Bullet.Character = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Character
                    .Bullet.Font.Name = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Name
                    .Bullet.Font.Bold = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Bold
                    .Bullet.Font.Size = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Size
                    .Bullet.UseTextColor = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.UseTextColor
                    .Bullet.RelativeSize = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.RelativeSize
                    If tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type = msoBulletNumbered Then
                        .Bullet.StartValue = tmpRange.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.StartValue
                        .Bullet.Style = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Style
                        .Bullet.Type = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type
                    End If
                Else
                    .Bullet.visible = msoFalse
                End If

                .Alignment = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.Alignment
                .BaseLineAlignment = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.BaseLineAlignment
                .HangingPunctuation = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.HangingPunctuation
                .TextDirection = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.TextDirection
                .WordWrap = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.WordWrap
                .IndentLevel = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.IndentLevel
                .LineRuleAfter = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.LineRuleAfter
                .LineRuleBefore = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.LineRuleBefore
                .LineRuleWithin = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.LineRuleWithin
                .SpaceAfter = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter
                .SpaceBefore = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore
                .SpaceWithin = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.SpaceWithin
                .LeftIndent = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent
                .FirstLineIndent = tmpRange2.Paragraphs(j).ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent
            End With
        Next

        For i = 1 To tmpRange.Words.Count
            With oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Words(i)
                .Font.Name = tmpRange.Words(i).Font.Name
                .Font.Size = tmpRange.Words(i).Font.Size
                If tmpRange.Words(i).Font.Color.Type = msoColorTypeScheme Then
                    .Font.Color.ObjectThemeColor = tmpRange.Words(i).Font.Color.ObjectThemeColor
                ElseIf tmpRange.Words(i).Font.Color.Type = msoColorTypeRGB Then
                    .Font.Color.RGB = tmpRange.Words(i).Font.Color.RGB
                ElseIf tmpRange.Words(i).Font.Color.Type = msoColorTypeMixed Then
                    For j = 1 To tmpRange.Words(i).Characters.Count
                        If tmpRange.Words(i).Characters(j).Font.Color.Type = msoColorTypeScheme Then
                            .Characters(j).Font.Color.ObjectThemeColor = tmpRange.Words(i).Characters(j).Font.Color.ObjectThemeColor
                        Else
                            .Characters(j).Font.Color.RGB = tmpRange.Words(i).Characters(j).Font.Color.RGB
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
                .Font.Bold = tmpRange.Words(i).Font.Bold
                .Font.Italic = tmpRange.Words(i).Font.Italic
                .Font.Underline = tmpRange.Words(i).Font.Underline
                .Font.Subscript = tmpRange.Words(i).Font.Subscript
                .Font.Superscript = tmpRange.Words(i).Font.Superscript
            End With
        Next

    End If
End If

Exit Sub

Errhandler:
Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: It is stunning that this is necessary to avoid using the clipboard. Thank you for posting this. What do your `o` and `t` prefixes stand for? I guessed `origin` and `target` but the method performs the copy in the opposite direction.